# Creating automated Microsoft Excel filtered list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have the following situation in one of my Excel sheets:

I have a table with some values, particularly "date", "stock" and "cost" among other data. The table may contain values from various different stocks, and I want to display a graph with all values regarding a specific selected stock (the value is put in a specific cell). So, from an algorithmic perspective, the user puts the desired stock he wants to see in a specific cell, Excel than looks inside the reference table seeking for lines where "stock" contains the selected stock, and after capturing all such lines, draws a graph with the corresponding values of the "cost" column.

*How can I do that?*

I did some research and found about the usage of "Filter" could be what I was looking for, but it didn't do the job nicely: it had to be done by direct clicking in the filter buttons above the table instead of by writting in a cell. Besides, when no specific stock is selected, the graph shows all "cost" data, becoming totally unnaceptable (when no stock is choosed, the graph should be empty).

Thanks for any help,

Momergil

Note: Using Excel 2007

Comment: Take a look at pivot tables, those should provide a rather easy clicky solution.

Comment: If you were on Excel 2010+ then I would say try a Pivot Table with Slicers.  It seems odd to be doing financial analysis using a 7 year-old version of Excel. Did you know you can get the latest version for about $100?

Comment: @MikeHoney yeah, I know my Excel is not updated, but that was the only Excel I could got and I don't think is valuable to spend some money in a software I rarely use to do more than coloured spreadsheets, not to mention I'm from Brazil and here such things are fare more expensive ;) (a student version, very limited, cost more than the amount you mentioned in reais)

Comment: @TheUser1024 I'll have a look at those. Thanks!